# Want to show more than 3 components of a Dashboard on the Home Screen

Tags: dashboard, home-page-component, home-page-layout

I have a dashboard that is having more than 3 dashboard components on it. I want to show all the components of that dashboard on the Home Page. I have tried it by creating an HTML component on Home Page Layout and iframe, but that didn't work. Instead, it printed my entire iframe code which I had written on the HTML Text Editor. Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Why? I think about the user experience having to look through all those charts on a tiny sub section of the page and it feels like crazy talk. Sometimes it's not can I do it? It's should I do it.

Comment: Well somebody else has already decided that they should do it, Its upto me now to achieve, that's why can I do it?

Comment: I suppose if you have to the iframe would work. Maybe posting your code people can make suggestions to edit.